# Problema con el buffer en c

Tags: c

tengo esta funcion.

```
void funcionNombres(){

  char rta;
  char nombres[30];

  printf("Ya diste de alta? (s/n) : ");
  scanf(" %c", &rta);

  if(rta == 'n' || rta == 'N'){
    printf("TENES QUE DAR DE ALTA.\n");

  }else if(rta == 's' || rta == 'S'){

    if(strlen(nombre[0]) == 0 || strlen(nombre[1]) == 0 || strlen(nombre[2]) == 0){
      printf("FALTAN DATOS.\n");

    }else{

      printf("Nombre del trabajador : ");
      fgets(nombres,sizeof(nombres),stdin);
      strtok(nombres, "\n");
      while(getchar() != '\n' && getchar() != EOF);

      for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        if(strcmp(nombres,nombre[i]) == 0){
          printf("Nombre : %s | Sueldo : %.2f | Numero : %d | Horas : %d\n",nombre[i],sueldo[i],numero[i],horas[i]);
          break;
        }else{
          continue;
        }
        printf("no se encontro el nombre.\n");
      }
    }
  }


}
```

Lo que tendria que hacer, es que desde la main, la llamo y tengo que poner un nombre y busca ese nombre entre , cuando pongo el nombre y doy enter, Me queda en negro.... Como que el bucle no termina y no entiendo porque. Creo que es un problema con el buffer. Tambien puede ser por un puntero creo. porfa ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te puede estar pasando con el buffer es que al intentar leer estas leyendo el caracter de nueva linea cuando queres hacer el `fgets`.

Lo que podes hacer es leer el primer caracter apenas escaneas.

```
  printf("Ya diste de alta? (s/n) : ");
  scanf(" %c", &rta);
  getchar(); // Consumir el carácter de nueva línea pendiente
```

Ademas con esto creo que ya no es necesario tu while, porque siempre vas a evitar ese salto, asi que yo probaria removiendo la linea

```
while(getchar() != '\n' && getchar() != EOF);
```

Si no sirve, ponela de vuelta.

Espero que sirva!